# constraint update cause item move when using hide button on push with autolayout

Tags: ios, autolayout, storyboard

first, please check out the problem (note the gray belt thing will be moved during the navigation push view)

[image: enter image dauto layout here]

I have made autolayout constraint with storyboard like this:

[image]

And to hide the tab bar to fully display the image(and prevent user to click to other tabs) I have `hide bottom bar on push` checked:

[image]

But now the gray belt is moving during view changing.

How to fix this?

Comment: Constrain the bottom to the `view.bottomAnchor`, and not to the `BottomLayoutGuide.top`.

Comment: @MilanNosáľ thanks, but how to do that? there is no such option when using ctrl+drag :-(

Comment: @MilanNosáľ just checked and find holding option will give alt options for the constraining :D thanks for that

Comment: I've added an answer, please accept/upvote, if it helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constrain the bottom to the `view.bottomAnchor`, and not to the `BottomLayoutGuide.top`. You can do it in attribute inspector when you select the constraint.

[image]